# ActionBarSherlock with Google map and fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-mapview

I am trying to compile this [example](http://blog.xavirigau.com/?p=39#comment-1075)

I am using:

android-support-v4-googlemaps

[ActionBarSherlock-Plugin-Maps v.4.0](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)

I have returned this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xrigau.mapsfragments/com.xrigau.mapsfragments.MapswithfragmentsActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MapViews can only be created inside instances of MapActivity.
```

at this line:

```
Exchanger.mMapView = new MapView(this, "INSERT_YOUR_MAP_API_KEY_HERE");
```

Can you help me to resolve this problem?

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // We instantiate the MapView here, it's really important!
        Exchanger.mMapView = new MapView(this, "INSERT_YOUR_MAP_API_KEY_HERE"); // TODO: Replace for API Key!

        setupFragments();
        // We manually show the list Fragment.
        showFragment(mMyListFragment);
    }
```

This is the entire file .java...This class extend SherlockFragmentActivity:

```
    package com.xrigau.mapsfragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockListFragment;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

public class MapswithfragmentsActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    private MapFragment mMapFragment;
    private MyListFragment mMyListFragment;

    // We use this fragment as a pointer to the visible one, so we can hide it easily.
    private Fragment mVisible = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // We instantiate the MapView here, it's really important!
        Exchanger.mMapView = new MapView(this, "INSERT_YOUR_MAP_API_KEY_HERE"); // TODO: Replace for API Key!

        setupFragments();
        // We manually show the list Fragment.
        showFragment(mMyListFragment);
    }

    /**
     * This method does the setting up of the Fragments. It basically checks if
     * the fragments exist and if they do, we'll hide them. If the fragments
     * don't exist, we create them, add them to the FragmentManager and hide
     * them.
     */
    private void setupFragments() {
        final FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        /*
         * If the activity is killed while in BG, it's possible that the
         * fragment still remains in the FragmentManager, so, we don't need to
         * add it again.
         */
        mMapFragment = (MapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(MapFragment.TAG);
        if (mMapFragment == null) {
            mMapFragment = new MapFragment();
            ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, mMapFragment, MapFragment.TAG);
        }
        ft.hide(mMapFragment);

        mMyListFragment = (MyListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(MyListFragment.TAG);
        if (mMyListFragment == null) {
            mMyListFragment = new MyListFragment();
            ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, mMyListFragment, MyListFragment.TAG);
        }
        ft.hide(mMyListFragment);

        ft.commit();
    }

    /**
     * This method shows the given Fragment and if there was another visible
     * fragment, it gets hidden. We can just do this because we know that both
     * the mMyListFragment and the mMapFragment were added in the Activity's
     * onCreate, so we just create the fragments once at first and not every
     * time. This will avoid facing some problems with the MapView.
     * 
     * @param fragmentIn
     *            The fragment to show.
     */
    private void showFragment(Fragment fragmentIn) {
        if (fragmentIn == null) return;

        final FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);

        if (mVisible != null) ft.hide(mVisible);

        ft.show(fragmentIn).commit();
        mVisible = fragmentIn;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu with the options to show the Map and the List.
        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.ic_list:
            // Show mMyListFragment.
            showFragment(mMyListFragment);
            return true;

        case R.id.ic_map:
            // Show mMapFragment.
            showFragment(mMapFragment);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * This class acts as an exchanger between the Activity and the MapFragment,
     * so if you want, you can put the MapFragment class in a separate java
     * file.
     * 
     * @author Xavi
     * 
     */
    public static class Exchanger {
        // We will use this MapView always.
        public static MapView mMapView;
    }

    /**
     * This is our ListFragment class. You can put it in a separate java file.
     * 
     * @author Xavi
     * 
     */
    public static class MyListFragment extends SherlockListFragment {

        public static final String TAG = "listFragment";

        private final String[] mItems = { "List Item 1", "List Item 2",
                "List Item 3", "List Item 4", "List Item 5", "List Item 6",
                "List Item 7", "List Item 8", "List Item 9", "List Item 10" };

        public MyListFragment() {}

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
            super.onCreate(arg0);
            setRetainInstance(true);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup vg, Bundle data) {
            // Inflate the ListView layout file.
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, null);
        }

        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View arg0, Bundle arg1) {
            super.onViewCreated(arg0, arg1);
            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getSherlockActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, mItems));
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is the Fragment class that will hold the MapView as its content
     * view. You can put it in a separate java file.
     * 
     * @author Xavi
     * 
     */
    public static class MapFragment extends SherlockFragment {

        public static final String TAG = "mapFragment";

        public MapFragment() {}

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
            super.onCreate(arg0);
            setRetainInstance(true);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup vg, Bundle data) {
            // The Activity created the MapView for us, so we can do some init stuff.
            Exchanger.mMapView.setClickable(true);
            Exchanger.mMapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true); // If you want.

            /*
             * If you're getting Exceptions saying that the MapView already has
             * a parent, uncomment the next lines of code, but I think that it
             * won't be necessary. In other cases it was, but in this case I
             * don't this should happen.
             */
            /*
             * final ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) Exchanger.mMapView.getParent();
             * if (parent != null) parent.removeView(Exchanger.mMapView);
             */

            return Exchanger.mMapView;
        }
    }
}
```

SherlockMapActivity.java:

```
      package com.actionbarsherlock.app;

    import android.content.res.Configuration;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.KeyEvent;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.Window;
    import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
    import com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock;
    import com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.OnActionModeFinishedListener;
    import com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.OnActionModeStartedListener;
    import com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.OnCreatePanelMenuListener;
    import com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.OnMenuItemSelectedListener;
    import com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.OnPreparePanelListener;
    import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
    import com.actionbarsherlock.view.ActionMode;
    import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
    import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater;
    import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
    import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;

    public abstract class SherlockMapActivity extends MapActivity implements OnCreatePanelMenuListener, OnPreparePanelListener, OnMenuItemSelectedListener, OnActionModeStartedListener, OnActionModeFinishedListener {
        private ActionBarSherlock mSherlock;

        protected final ActionBarSherlock getSherlock() {
            if (mSherlock == null) {
                mSherlock = ActionBarSherlock.wrap(this, ActionBarSherlock.FLAG_DELEGATE);
            }
            return mSherlock;
        }


        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Action bar and mode
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        public ActionBar getSupportActionBar() {
            return getSherlock().getActionBar();
        }

        public ActionMode startActionMode(ActionMode.Callback callback) {
            return getSherlock().startActionMode(callback);
        }

        @Override
        public void onActionModeStarted(ActionMode mode) {}

        @Override
        public void onActionModeFinished(ActionMode mode) {}


        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // General lifecycle/callback dispatching
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        @Override
        public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
            super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
            getSherlock().dispatchConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostResume() {
            super.onPostResume();
            getSherlock().dispatchPostResume();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            getSherlock().dispatchPause();
            super.onPause();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
            getSherlock().dispatchStop();
            super.onStop();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            getSherlock().dispatchDestroy();
            super.onDestroy();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            getSherlock().dispatchPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
            super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onTitleChanged(CharSequence title, int color) {
            getSherlock().dispatchTitleChanged(title, color);
            super.onTitleChanged(title, color);
        }

        @Override
        public final boolean onMenuOpened(int featureId, android.view.Menu menu) {
            if (getSherlock().dispatchMenuOpened(featureId, menu)) {
                return true;
            }
            return super.onMenuOpened(featureId, menu);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPanelClosed(int featureId, android.view.Menu menu) {
            getSherlock().dispatchPanelClosed(featureId, menu);
            super.onPanelClosed(featureId, menu);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
            if (getSherlock().dispatchKeyEvent(event)) {
                return true;
            }
            return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            getSherlock().dispatchSaveInstanceState(outState);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
            getSherlock().dispatchRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        }

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Native menu handling
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        public MenuInflater getSupportMenuInflater() {
            return getSherlock().getMenuInflater();
        }

        @Override
        public void invalidateOptionsMenu() {
            getSherlock().dispatchInvalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void supportInvalidateOptionsMenu() {
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public final boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
            return getSherlock().dispatchCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }

        @Override
        public final boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
            return getSherlock().dispatchPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        }

        @Override
        public final boolean onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem item) {
            return getSherlock().dispatchOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        @Override
        public void openOptionsMenu() {
            if (!getSherlock().dispatchOpenOptionsMenu()) {
                super.openOptionsMenu();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void closeOptionsMenu() {
            if (!getSherlock().dispatchCloseOptionsMenu()) {
                super.closeOptionsMenu();
            }
        }


        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


  // Sherlock menu handling
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    @Override
    public boolean onCreatePanelMenu(int featureId, Menu menu) {
        if (featureId == Window.FEATURE_OPTIONS_PANEL) {
            return onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreparePanel(int featureId, View view, Menu menu) {
        if (featureId == Window.FEATURE_OPTIONS_PANEL) {
            return onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
        if (featureId == Window.FEATURE_OPTIONS_PANEL) {
            return onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return false;
    }


    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Content
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    @Override
    public void addContentView(View view, LayoutParams params) {
        getSherlock().addContentView(view, params);
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentView(int layoutResId) {
        getSherlock().setContentView(layoutResId);
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentView(View view, LayoutParams params) {
        getSherlock().setContentView(view, params);
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentView(View view) {
        getSherlock().setContentView(view);
    }

    public void requestWindowFeature(long featureId) {
        getSherlock().requestFeature((int)featureId);
    }


    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Progress Indication
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public void setSupportProgress(int progress) {
        getSherlock().setProgress(progress);
    }

    public void setSupportProgressBarIndeterminate(boolean indeterminate) {
        getSherlock().setProgressBarIndeterminate(indeterminate);
    }

    public void setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(boolean visible) {
        getSherlock().setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(visible);
    }

    public void setSupportProgressBarVisibility(boolean visible) {
        getSherlock().setProgressBarVisibility(visible);
    }

    public void setSupportSecondaryProgress(int secondaryProgress) {
        getSherlock().setSecondaryProgress(secondaryProgress);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems from the exception that you have extended Activity and not MapActivity.

Change

```
public class MyMapActivity extends Activity {
```

to

```
public class MyMapActivity extends MapActivity {
```

And also you might consider adding

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

in manifest file if you haven't already.

Comment: the class extend SherlockFragmentActivity

Comment: Sorry about the hasty reply, you had not added the entire class which got me confused. I went through the tutorial and the source in github. Can you follow SherlockFragmentActivity and check what it extends? Does it extend MapActivity at any point? And also you might want to check if you have old jar's( android-support-v4) in your build path instead of  android-support-v4-googlemaps.

Comment: I have not found android-support-v4

Comment: Does any of the Classes that you extended from like SherlockFragmentActivity, SherlockListFragment or SherlockFragment end up extending Activity present in android-support-v4-googlemaps? and does that Activity extend MapActivity?

Comment: mmm I have only this 2 files reported in question